# Grading large enrollment courses

Tags: mathematics, exams, grading

I am the coordinator of several sections of a course with over 200 students. The midterm exam is common and everyone takes the same exam at the same time. We do have TAs. What are some efficient ways to have TAs grade papers? It seems using any online grading platform, such as Gradescope, would be extremely time-consuming as papers need to be scanned first and that takes a long time.

Comment: For what it's worth I've had the opposite experience with online grading platforms: the time spent scanning is a very insignificant drop in the bucket if you have a copier with an auto feeding scanner.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to make it a "social event". The exam happens in the morning. Me and the TAs eat something (I am paying), and than we go in a room with a large table, each gets one problem to grade and we pass the exams along. I am at the table to, grading. That way we can naturally discuss any border cases, or things in the rubic that aren't clear, etc. The aim is to get through that pile of exams in one day.

Answer (score 1):

Split the TA's into as many groups as there are problems.  Each group grades its problem on all of the papers, using a well prepared rubric, and reviewing a sample of papers before hand to validate the rubric and get the TAs grading to a common standard.

Comment: It is easiest to bundle the papers into bundles of say 10 to 20 papers (randomize the pilled to avoid grading all of the papers from a section together.)